# how to add my project to svn which is already added to svn before in intellij IDEA

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, version-control

I get project by flashdisk which the project directory is already added on SVN(Subversion).

How to connect my project to SVN by using Intellij ? I do not want to commit whole project to its current SVN directory. Could you please help me how to do that ?

Regards
Alper

Comment: What does "link to SVN" mean exactly?

Comment: I meant Apache Subversion

Comment: What I mean is that "linking" does not belong to Subversion terminology so we can't know what it means unless you tell us. Do you by chance mean that you've exported a directory tree and now you want the folder to become a working copy again?

Comment: I changed the question completely. You can read  the edited question above

Comment: Please open the directory in your operating system file manager. Is there a `.idea` object in the root folder? And a `.svn` object?

Comment: yep there is .idea and .svn object

Comment: Then your folder is already both things: an IDE project and a Subversion working copy. Sorry, I can't help you because I'm unable to understand what your question is. Maybe someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If your project's SVN working copy was delivered to you on a USB stick, you can copy it to your computer and open it in IntelliJ IDEA as-is. IDEA should recognize the project as versioned by SVN. Normally, you don't need to re-add it to the remote repository because its already versioned.

You may want to read the documentation at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-subversion-integration.html